# Unix : saving a sed command in a variable, to echo it, then execute it

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I would like to execute a (for example `sed`) command and `echo` it before it is executed.

I tried to save the command in a variable.
Then, `echo` it and execute it:

```
command="sed -i 's/FOO/BAR/g' myFile";
echo "Command: \"$command\"" ;
$command ;
```

Error I got :

```
Command: "sed -i 's/FOO/BAR/g' myFile"
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''
```

**How should I escape the single quotes?** (or may I use double quotes ?)

I googled it, but found no answer.

Comment: `expect` seems to be the answer.

Comment: Better to use: `(set -x; sed-i 's/FOO/BAR/g' myFile)` to get the shell trace output of the `sed` command (only).  It avoids all the many complications of escaping the code so it can be re-evaluated properly.  You could use `eval` in this context; it is not something to play with lightly, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a convenience function to echo any given command, then to run it.

```
verbosely_do () {
  printf 'Command: %s\n' "$*";  # printf, not echo, because $@ might contain switches to echo
  "$@";
}

verbosely_do sed -i 's/FOO/BAR/g' myFile
```

This will give you:

```
Command: sed -i s/FOO/BAR/g myFile
```

and then perform the sed(1) command.

Comment: I like this way. I wanted to write a script, and a way to "echo" the commands that are executed. This way, I havn't to escape arguments, which helps a lot !  

What do you mean with _printf, not echo, because $@ might contain switches to echo_ ? You meant $* ? or $@ ? What means _contain switches to echo_ ?

Comment: @el_teedee, the `echo` command is actually [specified not to recognize `--`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html#tag_20_37_04).  So, something like `echo $FOO`, where `FOO="-n whatever"` might not do what you want, since you cannot stop `echo` from interpreting the `-n` as an option.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is to just remove the single quotes: sed is interpreting them as part of the sed program:

```
command="sed -i s/FOO/BAR/g myFile"
$command
```

That clearly won't be appropriate for more complicated sed scripts (e.g. those that include whitespace or semi-colons).

The correct answer, assuming you use a shell that has arrays (bash, ksh, zsh) is:

```
command=(sed -i 's/FOO/BAR/g' myFile)
echo "Command: \"${command[*]}\""
"${command[@]}"  # the quotes are required here
```

See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays

Comment: Indeed, I must use single / double quotes, since my regexp may contain  spaces.  

I read the Arrays' link, that's a bit complicated :) You say _the quotes are required here_ for the shell expansion on $command to works ? (@pilcrow uses the same quotes around `"$@"` in this example for the same reason I think ?)

Comment: Yes, using quotes means the array is expanded into the individual elements, no quotes means the array is expanded into the space-delimited words. Try this test: `a=("1 2" "3 4"); set -- ${a[@]}; echo $#; set -- "${a[@]}"; echo $#`

Answer (score 2):

The use of `$command` bypasses the shell expansion and thus the single quotes are passed in the argument to `sed`. Either loose the single quotes or use `eval $command`.

Comment: I cannot remove quotes since my regexp may contain spaces, etc... And I recently wrote that `eval` should be used with precaution.

Comment: Escaping, spaces and what not is always a drag in a shell. If you want to escape (pun intended) all that, I would generate a shell script that performs the `sed` command. That is easier than escaping through all levels of expansion and is easy to debug.